# Erlang :: Why rpc:pmap call in erlang does not works for string library functions?

Tags: string, functional-programming, erlang, match

```
string:find("This is a test wa.me/123456 message alibaba","wa.me").
```

Works fine matches wa.me but below code

```
erpc:pmap({string,find},["This is a test wa.me/123456 message alibaba"],["wa.me"]).
```

Does not works , let me if anyone knows the reason of failure

Thanks

Tried  this

```
erpc:pmap({string,find},["This is a test wa.me/123456 message alibaba"],["wa.me"]).
```

Expects
`wa.me/123456 message alibaba`

but got

```
[nomatch]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `erps:pmap/3` function in the first place, `pmap/3` is exported from `rpc` module.

Then, the order of arguments is given below:

```elixir
  @spec pmap(funcSpec, extraArgs, list1) :: list2
        when funcSpec: {module, function},
             module: module(),
             function: atom(),
             extraArgs: [term()],
             list1: [elem :: term()],
             list2: [term()]
```

That said, the proper call would be

```elixir
rpc:pmap({string, find}, ["wa.me"], ["This is a test wa.me/123456 message alibaba"])
#⇒ ["wa.me/123456 message alibaba"]
```